# Intersecting any number of Lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, intersection

Say i have any number of lists

```
List<int> List1 = new List<int>();
List<int> List2 = new List<int>();
List<int> ListN = new List<int>();
```

How can i get a final list which contains only those elements which are present in every list.

I initially did this with many loops. However i was not satisfied. With my limited knowledge of LINQ i think it should be easy to do however i don't know where to even start.

Is there any other way to do this, preferably with LINQ.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to automagically look for these lists as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
var intersection = List1.Intersect(List2).Intersect(List3);
```

Or if you want to easily support *n* number of lists:

```
var lists = new List<List<string>>();

lists.Add(new List<string>(new string[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" }));
lists.Add(new List<string>(new string[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test4" }));
lists.Add(new List<string>(new string[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test5" }));
lists.Add(new List<string>(new string[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test6" }));

var aggregate = lists.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>{
                           List2, ..., ListN
                         };
IEnumerable<int> result = List1;
foreach(var list in lists){
  result = result.Intersect(list);
  if(!result.Any()) break;
}
//Use ToList() on result to get List<int>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Intersect`

```
var r = List1.Intersect(List2).Intersect(ListN);
```

Example:

```
var r = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    .Intersect(new [] { 2, 3, 4, 5 })
    .Intersect(new [] { 3, 4, 5, 6 });
// r now contains 3, 4
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx

Here is an extension method that takes a list of lists and performs the intersection on them all. Same as above, but simpler to use perhaps?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAll<T>(
   this IEnumerable<T> list, 
   params IEnumerable<T>[] otherLists
) {
    foreach (var otherList in otherLists)
    {
        list = list.Intersect(otherList);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Usage:

```
var r = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
     .IntersectAll(new [] { 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new [] { 3, 4, 5, 6 });
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could use the `Intersect` method of LINQ, that will result in constantly taking the current intersection and re-populating a new `HashSet` with those items.  By using your own explicit `HashSet` you can much more efficiently get the intersection of N sequences:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> intersectAll<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();

        var set = new HashSet<T>(iterator.Current);
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
            set.IntersectWith(iterator.Current);

        return set;
    }
}
```